# ld: library not found for -lPods

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, cocoapods

I've upgraded to cocoapods 0.32.1 today and I get the linker error above. I've tried virtually any advice I could find and nothing works.

I've run pod install, which created a workspace which I'm using to build the project.

What seems weird to me is that the Pods project generated by default contains i386 and x86_64 architectures instead of arm ones.

[image: Default Pods project settings]

```
Pods was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libPods.a' because its architectures 'x86_64' didn't contain all required architectures 'i386 x86_64'
```

Then I changed Architectures of the Pods project to Universal and Build Active Architecture Only to No for both Debug and Release.

And I still get the same linker error, but with no warnings now.

I'm totally clueless now, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is tagged iOS and yet those Xcode settings are for OSX.  What's that about?

Comment: That's the project generate by default by 'pod install'. Even though I have "platform :ios, '7.0'" in my Podfile

Comment: Erm, OK, so why is the linker complaining about `x86_64` which is **not** an iOS architecture?

Comment: It seems wrong that build settings for Pods project contain ios settings in the first place.

Comment: I don't understand; it's an iOS project, so why wouldn't it?

Comment: Might be an issue with cocoapods xcode project generator. Here is something similar: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/issues/144